# vagrant up hangs on ssh

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I did `vagrant up --provision libvirt` and it hangs on:

```
default: Waiting for SSH to become available...
```

I can do `vagrant ssh`. it works! but I can't understand why vagrant up hangs on ssh mode.
I delete all the machine from my local. build again. doesnt solve an issue.
Also, reinstall plugins doesn't help.
Also, delete the .vagrant file from my repo!
I remove inscure-keypair from .vagrant.d
I did `vagrant reload`

The issue is this error actually:

```
An action 'up' was attempted on the machine 'default',
but another process is already executing an action on the machine.
Vagrant locks each machine for access by only one process at a time.
Please wait until the other Vagrant process finishes modifying this
machine, then try again.

If you believe this message is in error, please check the process
listing for any "ruby" or "vagrant" processes and kill them. Then
try again.
```

I killed all ruby and vagrant process but doesn't help
Vagrant version: 1.9.4
vagrant-libvirt version: 0.0.37
ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into similar issue when trying to run `vagrant up --provider=lxc`
I got it fixed simply by checking to see if any ruby/vagrant process was already running and kill it.
FYI, In my case, the `vagrant up` process initiated by me prior to the current run was still running.

```
$ ps -ef | grep ruby
$ ps -ef | grep vagrant

$ kill -9

$ Restart "vagrant up --provider=lxc"
```

Comment: Vagrant is weird. Whenever I run into this issue I do `vagrant reload` - sometimes it works at the first attempt, sometimes at the 10th.